# React Native - Display datas from async AsyncStorage.getItems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-native

Basically, on my app people have to validate when they succeed on a challenge.
When they click on the validation button, I save the "key":"value" of the challenge with the function :

```
async function validate(challenge_nb)
{
 try {
   await AsyncStorage.setItem(challenge_nb, 'OK');
 } catch (error) {
   console.log("error")
 }
}
```

It works fine.

Now, I would like to get back that data and display it in a list... And I've no idea about how to do that.

I was trying to use that kind of function to get all key/value that I saved :

```
async function getalldatas()
{
AsyncStorage.getAllKeys((err, keys) => {
AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (err, stores) => {
 stores.map((result, i, store) => {
   // get at each store's key/value so you can work with it
   let key = store[i][0];
   let value = store[i][1];
   console.log(value);
  });
});
```

});
}

But I don't know how to display that in my render() function... Moreover cause it's async

Actually, I would like to do a kind of :

render (
   For each key/value :
     key : value
   end_foreach
)

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

You can store it to a state value then have a conditional render, p.s. never put stuff like this in your render, make it a method of your component:

```
getAllDatas = () => {
  AsyncStorage.getAllKeys((err, keys) => {
    AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (err, stores) => {
      this.setState({ stores });
    });
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      {this.state.stores.length && this.state.stores.map(item =>
        <Text>{`${item[0]}: ${item[1}`}</Text>)}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you !
So I called the getAllDatas in the componentDidMount() method.

But before being able to use the state, I have to init it in my constructor... What value can I put in my this.state = {    stores : ??? } at init ?

Comment: yeah, so just have it start as an empty array: `this.state = { stores : [] }`